# Show monthly time log in desired format

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a pivot to do this but can't quite figure it out.
I have two tables `accesslog` and `employee`

```
RCID    EmployeeID          LogDate     LogTime   IN/OUT
559     050098              8/18/2015   15:53:14    3
586     050098              8/19/2015   07:14:09    0
587     050098              8/19/2015   07:14:19    0
640     050098              8/19/2015   12:32:31    1
643     050098              8/19/2015   12:33:48    2
661     050098              8/19/2015   17:17:00    3
678     050098              8/20/2015   07:12:41    0
723     050098              8/20/2015   12:31:35    1
724     050098              8/20/2015   12:34:28    2
736     050098              8/20/2015   16:56:04    3
863     050098              8/25/2015   07:47:45    0
927     050098              8/25/2015   12:48:57    1
928     050098              8/25/2015   12:53:23    2
952     050098              8/25/2015   17:20:05    3
972     050098              8/26/2015   07:41:54    0
1016    050098              8/26/2015   12:14:11    1
1017    050098              8/26/2015   12:17:19    2
1051    050098              8/26/2015   17:07:16    3
1084    050098              8/27/2015   07:39:04    0
1119    050098              8/27/2015   12:20:56    1
1123    050098              8/27/2015   12:23:34    2
1153    050098              8/27/2015   17:25:57    3
1270    050098              9/1/2015    07:41:44    0
1292    050098              9/1/2015    12:14:06    1
1294    050098              9/1/2015    12:15:34    2
1324    050098              9/1/2015    17:19:00    3
1355    050098              9/3/2015    07:39:25    0
1399    050098              9/3/2015    12:17:29    1
1401    050098              9/3/2015    12:21:41    2
1419    050098              9/3/2015    17:09:23    3
1445    050098              9/4/2015    07:24:23    0
1510    050098              9/4/2015    12:58:15    1
1511    050098              9/4/2015    12:59:36    2
1536    050098              9/4/2015    17:40:01    3
1562    050098              9/7/2015    07:03:31    0
1637    050098              9/7/2015    17:34:07    3
1649    050098              9/8/2015    07:11:26    0
1709    050098              9/8/2015    17:13:09    3
1734    050098              9/9/2015    07:44:49    0
1755    050098              9/9/2015    12:09:06    1
1760    050098              9/9/2015    12:12:30    2
```

Employee table;

```
employee_id     firtsname     lastname
050098          Alex          Nomam
050057          Mandy         Hampton
```

Can I use a Pivot to display this table like this?

Name : Alex Nomam
Month: August 2015

```
                  AM                        PM
           In            Out           In            Out
1     
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11.
12
13
14
15
16
17
18        07:14:19
19        07:14:19     12:32:31         12:33:48     17:17:00
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

I'm using php and mssql please help me i'm new in php and sql

see a screen rep [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjBjU.png)

Comment: There can be different functionality in mysql and mssql may one work for mysql but not in mssql so you should tag only mssql.

Comment: Can you paraphrase your question and provide more details? I don't understand the last output:                   AM                        PM
           In            Out           In            Out -- what is this? and how it should be evaluated? And how this  Name : Alex Nomam Month: August 2015 is related to the table below? Please, provide the exact output that you want to get

Comment: its sql 2008 r2 sir @DhruvJoshi

Comment: sir @user1551066 its attendance report for the month of august.

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @firstname varchar(30), @lastname varchar(30), @Month date
SET @firstname='Alex'
SET @lastname='Nomam'
SET @Month= '08/01/2015'
DECLARE @endDay int

SET @endDay=
   DAY( DATEADD( MONTH, 1 + DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,
        CAST(YEAR(@Month) * 10000 + MONTH(@Month) * 100 + 01 AS NVARCHAR(20))),-1))

select 
    [day], 
    [0] as [AM In], 
    [1] as [AM Out], 
    [2] as [PM In], 
    [3] as [PM out]
from 
 daysOfMonth d left join 
(
  select 
     LogDate, LogTime ,[In/Out] 
  from 
     accesslog a left join employee e 
       on a.EmployeeID=e.Employee_id  
  where 
     firstname=@firstname and 
     lastname=@lastname and 
     MONTH(LogDate)=MONTH(@Month) and 
     YEAR(LogDate)=YEAR(@Month)
) s
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(LogTime) for [In/Out] in ([0],[1],[2],[3])
)p
on d.[day]=DAY(Logdate)
where [day]<=@endDay
```

**Explanation:**

So this has actually two problems in it.
One is pivoting and calculating the times for a date and other is showing it in the manner for all dates of the month.

To calculate dates of month I assumed a table `daysofmonth` which has days 1-31 in int column.

I expcted that you'd pass  `@firstname` , `@lastname` and `@month` parameters for query.

```
 DECLARE @firstname varchar(30), @lastname varchar(30), @Month date
```

Using the `@month` parameter I was able to calculate the last date of month which served in the where clause when showing final values for each day of month

```
SET @endDay = DAY( DATEADD(
                            MONTH, 
                            1 + DATEDIFF(
                                          MONTH,
                                          0,
                                          CAST(
                                                YEAR(@Month) * 10000 
                                                + MONTH(@Month) * 100 
                                                + 01 
                                                AS NVARCHAR(20)
                                                )
                                        ),
                            -1
                            )
                    )
```

Also the pivot calculation can be expressed as

```
select * 
    from
(
  select 
     LogDate, LogTime ,[In/Out] 
  from 
    accesslog a left join employee e 
        on a.EmployeeID=e.Employee_id  
  where 
    firstname=@firstname and 
    lastname=@lastname and 
    MONTH(LogDate)=MONTH(@Month) and 
    YEAR(LogDate)=YEAR(@Month)
) s
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(LogTime) for [In/Out] in ([0],[1],[2],[3])
)p
```

Now we simply `left join` this `pivot` output to the `daysofmonth` table and add the `@endDay` clause in `where` condition to get the desired output.

**Demo SQL fiddle link:** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2d23/11